# Can you use Counters and Stances while swimming? (and other non-standing positions)

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat, tome-of-battle

Game situation:

Warblade with active stance: Pearl of Black Doubt. Warblade jumps in the lake, and is attacked by demon-humans with unarmed strike and spitting acid.

Can I apply the dodge benefits of the Stance and any possible counter maneuvers while swimming?

Character isn't actually 'standing' on anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stone Dragon specifies that its maneuvers (stances included) require one to be standing on solid ground. If you were at the bottom of the lake, fine, but swimming, they’re a no-go.

But all the other disciplines, such as the Diamond Mind discipline that offers *pearl of black doubt*, lack that restriction, and can be used just fine while swimming. And the limitation on Stone Dragon is rather unpopular from what I have seen, an unnecessary restriction that automatically drops the otherwise-decent Stone Dragon discipline to the bottom of the barrel as the worst discipline in the book.